# Check if text contains url, email and phone number with php and regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a text, for example, like: 
*$descrizione = "Tel.+39.1234.567899 asd.test@testwebsite.com
www.testwebsite.com*" 
and I would like to obtain three different variable with:
"*+39.1234.567899"
"asd.test@testwebsite.com"

"www.testwebsite.com*".
To check if text contains email I use regex and I write this code:

```
$regex = '/[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})/';
if (preg_match($regex, $descrizione, $email_is)) {
     for($e = 0; $e < count($email_is) ; $e++){
          if(strpos($email_is[$e], "@") !== false){
               $linkEmail = $email_is[$e];
          }
     }
}
```

now, I would like to find website url, so I try to write:

```
$regex = '/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi';
if( preg_match($regex, $descrizione, $matches)){
     $linkWebsite = $matches[0];
}
```

but the preg_match return false. I control the regex with the website http://regexr.com/ and it's correct, so I don't understand why return always false. Where is the problem?
I try to use `"/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/"` but I have the same problem and I try to check errors with trycatch but it doesn't return errors.
Finally I would like to find phone number but I don't know how to write regex.
Is there someone thet can help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution, I hope thet this can help someone.
The **preg_match** returns **only first result** and not all the result thet it has find.
So, if I check the regex using a website like regex101, it returns the corrects result with all matches, but if I use the same regex in php, it returns only one.
The regex option **"g"** **(global = don't return after first match)** corresponds to the function **preg_match_all**.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex fails because it's faulty. You've *escaped* the slashes (`/`) with slashes. You should use backslashes:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)?
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3bVakE/1).

Since regexr uses JS regex it doesn't complain, but if you try it at regex101 selecting php you'll easily detect such errors.

About regex for phone numbers - search! E.g https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+phone+number

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried your regex but it returns only "asd.test@testwebsite.com" and not "www.testwebsite.com". For phone numbers, I have searched a lot, obviously, but all solutions didn't work for me, always return false.

Comment: Actually, it's not my regex... It's yours. I simply pointed out the error in it ;) Since you allow `@` in the character class, email addresses get interpreted as an url. Maybe you could use something like `(?:https?:\/\/)?\w[-\w]*\.[-\w.]+([\/?]|(?= )|$)` for the url and `\w[-\w.+]*@\w[-\w]*\.[-\w.]+((?= )|$)` for the email?

Comment: ClasG sorry for the delay. I don't know why but if I try the regex on regex101.com is correct, if I try with my code the result is different.